# How were scripts duplicated before 1970?

Tags: production

Before the days of mimeographs and xerox machines, it must have been problematic to duplicate scripts. How was it done before 1970?

Comment: Lots of typewriters with lots of typists

Comment: I cannot answer, but mimeo's and methods of carbon paper copying have been around since the late 19th C. in one form or another so I am sure they were able to cobble something together.

Comment: Yes, it seems strange to specifically mention a duplication technique which pre-dates 1970 in your question.  I remember such devices being used for copying lecture notes or low circulation magazines before photocopying/xerox machines became cheap enough to use in quantity.  Not sure whether it or typewriters and copy paper were used for scripts though.

Comment: Erm Set type has been around for centuries. Printing is ancient.... But typists seems the more likely method.

Comment: My school issued homework assignments duplicated on a Banda machine in the mid 1960s.  Your question is based on a misconception of the availability of duplication.

Comment: 1960s. Be School internal exams & the school newspaper done on a hand turned Gestetner duplicator.

Comment: @Chenmunka I did not say duplication methods did not exist. I am simply asking WHAT they were.

Comment: @TylerDurden: Point taken.

Comment: https://www.abaa.org/blog/post/collecting-film-scripts

Comment: Looks like mimeography predates the film industry. That said, I wouldn’t be surprised if smaller productions or certain situations involved copyists who worked in teams to type up the copies. How music was copied for film scores and musical theatre before the 2000s was by hand!

Comment: It looks like the recent book [*The Celluloid Paper Trail*](https://www.oakknoll.com/pages/books/130880/kevin-r-johnson/celluloid-paper-trail-identification-and-description-of-twentieth-century-film-scripts-the) goes into some detail about how scripts were reproduced (with an eye towards identifying "legitimate" shooting scripts for collectors.)  It might be worth trying to get your hands on a copy if you're curious to learn more.

Answer (score 5):

We can see evidence of both mimeographs and typing pools being used in [this *Casablanca* shooting script](https://www.bonhams.com/auctions/21427/lot/104/) sold at auction in 2013.  From the description:

> The primary text present in this copy is the **mimeographed shooting version** of June 1, 1942 with pink and blue **mimeo revision pages** dated from June 5, June 13, and July 16 1942 bound in; present also are 26 **typed pages**, dated May 22, June 9 and July 14, 1942, bound in. The blue typed pages from July 14 (pp 147-149 as paginated) are titled "changes in new ending," and reflect the final direction of the last act of the film.

From this description, it sounds like the initial shooting scripts were mimeographed, and revision pages could either be mimeographed or typed depending on the circumstances.

It is not clear from this one data point why some pages might have been typed while others were mimeographed;  whether other studios relied more on typing than mimeograph machines or vice versa;  whether these practices changed over time;  or any number of other details.  Still, it is an interest glimpse into how duplication was done.